# Swift implement LiteralConvertible protocol

Tags: swift

I'm trying to implement the IntegerLiteralConvertible protocol on `UIColor`.  What I'd really like to do is this

```
 let black: UIColor = 0x000000
```

I first tried following the swift blog here https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=8 which doesn't work out of the box.  It seems according to swift in flux https://github.com/ksm/SwiftInFlux#literalconvertible-protocols-use-constructor that they are no longer using convertFromIntegerLiteral anymore and instead use the initializer.  So accordingly this is what we should have:

```
extension UIColor: IntegerLiteralConvertible {
    public convenience init(integerLiteral value: IntegerLiteralType) {
    UIColor(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
    }
}
```

But then what goes inside the initializer?  I can't set self. I'd like to say something like

```
self.init(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
```

that doesn't work and neither does anything else it seems.  I get the error "initializer requirement init(IntegerLiteral) can only be satisfied by a 'required' initializer in the definiation of non final class 'UIColor' " which isn't very helpful.  Any ideas of how to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the (workaround) code for Swift 2.0:

```
public class Color: UIColor, IntegerLiteralConvertible {

    public typealias IntegerLiteralType = UInt32

    public required init(integerLiteral value: IntegerLiteralType) {

        let a = CGFloat((value & 0xFF000000) >> 24) / 255.0
        let r = CGFloat((value & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0
        let g = CGFloat((value & 0xFF00) >> 8) / 255.0
        let b = CGFloat((value & 0xFF)) / 255.0

        super.init(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: a)
    }

    required public init(colorLiteralRed red: Float, green: Float, blue: Float, alpha: Float) {

        super.init(red: CGFloat(red), green: CGFloat(green), blue: CGFloat(blue), alpha: CGFloat(alpha))
    }

    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

Comment: `IntegerLiteralConvertible` is renamed to `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral` in Swift 3.0

Answer (score 1):

If you just write

```
let black = 0x000000
```

there is no way Swift can know you want to define a color. There is just a literal hexadecimal number, so `black` will simply be an integer by type inference.

Maybe you are looking for something like

```
let black : UIColor = 0x000000
```

But I think that the way you are going about it might be unnecessarily complicated. The most natural way is to simply write an initializer that takes an int.

```
extension UIColor {
    convenience init(_ hex: Int) {
        // add code to analyze the Int 
        // and generate appropriate r, g, b, as CGFloat
        return self.init(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: 1)
    }
}
```

Notice the underscore before the argument name which lets you omit it. Now you can create your color succinctly:

```
let black = UIColor(0x000000)
```

Comment: That doesn't work because Xcode says the only value you can return from init is nil.  Anyways I'm not looking for a convenience initializer.  What i'm looking to do is implement a LiteralConvertible, which in this case is with an Integer but could also be a String.  This used to be easy to do before Xcode 6.1 Beta 3.  Matt Thompson published some hander implementations for various cocoa class but they don't work this this change either https://github.com/mattt/Literally

Comment: Hmmm. I understand, sorry it did not work out for you. Just your first statement is not quite accurate - I tested it and it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like given the changes in Swift 1.1 this isn't possible anymore.  Hopefully this changes in a future release.

https://devforums.apple.com/message/1057171#1057171

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it seems with Swift 1.1 the only work around for this is either class extension or struct composition :/

```
class MyColor : UIColor,  IntegerLiteralConvertible {
    required init(integerLiteral value: IntegerLiteralType) {
        //code to set values from int ...
        super.init(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 1.0)
    }
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}

var x:MyColor = 0x00FF00
println(x)
```