# NSURL extension to adopt StringLiteralConvertible

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, nsurl

According to this [post](http://nshipster.com/swift-literal-convertible/) from NSHipster, we have extended the `NSURL` class to initialize `NSURL` objects using literals like this:

```
// the following is a full fledged NSURL object
let url: NSURL = "http://nshipster.com/"
```

Unfortunately, the post was written when Swift was first announced and it no longer compiles.

I was able to get my own custom object to conform to `StringLiteralConvertible`, and it looked like this:

```
final class Dog {
  let name: String

  init(name: String) {
    self.name = name
  }
}

// MARK: - StringLiteralConvertible
extension Dog: StringLiteralConvertible {
  typealias UnicodeScalarLiteralType = StringLiteralType
  typealias ExtendedGraphemeClusterLiteralType = StringLiteralType

  convenience init(unicodeScalarLiteral value: UnicodeScalarLiteralType) {
    self.init(stringLiteral: value)
  }

  convenience init(extendedGraphemeClusterLiteral value: ExtendedGraphemeClusterLiteralType) {
    self.init(stringLiteral: value)
  }

  convenience init(stringLiteral value: StringLiteralType) {
    self.init(name: value)
  }
}
```

This works great. For example, the following 2 lines of code will create a `Dog` object:

```
let dog = Dog(name: "Bob")
let dog: Dog = "Bob"
```

Unfortunately, using this strategy via extending `NSURL` was met with errors:

```
extension NSURL: StringLiteralConvertible {
  public typealias UnicodeScalarLiteralType = StringLiteralType
  public typealias ExtendedGraphemeClusterLiteralType = StringLiteralType

  convenience public init?(unicodeScalarLiteral value: UnicodeScalarLiteralType) {
    self.init(stringLiteral: value)
  }

  convenience public init?(extendedGraphemeClusterLiteral value: ExtendedGraphemeClusterLiteralType) {
    self.init(stringLiteral: value)
  }

  convenience public init?(stringLiteral value: StringLiteralType) {
    self.init(string: value)
  }
}
```

I've been trekking through the compiler errors, solving them 1 guess at a time. However, I can't get past the following error that occurs for each of the initializers:

`Initializer requirement 'init(...)' can only be satisfied by a 'required' initializer in the definition of non-final class 'NSURL'`

Adding the `required` keyword will give the error that you may not declared required initializers within extensions.

Looking for some directions :|

Comment: Seems to be impossible with the current Swift, compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26498391/swift-implement-literalconvertible-protocol.

Comment: It doesn't seem possible to do that in Swift 2: https://medium.com/bloc-posts/swift-simple-safe-inflexible-68ff6fa927dc

Comment: Seems to be the case. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## StringLiteralConvertible support

Unfortunately, `StringLiteralConvertible` support for `NSURL` seems to be not possible in the current Swift version (2.2). The closest I can get is the following:

```
extension NSURL: StringLiteralConvertible {

    public convenience init(stringLiteral value: String) {
        self.init(string: value)!
    }

    public convenience init(extendedGraphemeClusterLiteral value: String) {
        self.init(string: value)!
    }

    public convenience init(unicodeScalarLiteral value: String) {
        self.init(string: value)!
    }

}
```

But the compiler complains:

```
Playground execution failed: OS X Playground.playground:5:24: error: initializer requirement 'init(stringLiteral:)' can only be satisfied by a `required` initializer in the definition of non-final class 'NSURL'
    public convenience init(stringLiteral value: String) {
                       ^
OS X Playground.playground:3:24: error: initializer requirement 'init(extendedGraphemeClusterLiteral:)' can only be satisfied by a `required` initializer in the definition of non-final class 'NSURL'
    public convenience init(extendedGraphemeClusterLiteral value: String) {
                       ^
OS X Playground.playground:7:24: error: initializer requirement 'init(unicodeScalarLiteral:)' can only be satisfied by a `required` initializer in the definition of non-final class 'NSURL'
    public convenience init(unicodeScalarLiteral value: String) {
```

And `required` initializers cannot be implemented in an extension.

## Alternative solution

We can simplify string-to-URL conversion from the other side!

```
extension String {

    var url: NSURL? {
        return NSURL(string: self)
    }

}

var url = "http://google.coom/".url
print(url?.scheme) // Optional("http")
```

Answer (score 0):

An another alternative is to subclass `NSURL` and conform to `StringLiteralConvertible` there.

```
class URL: NSURL, StringLiteralConvertible {

    <#...#>
}
```