# How do I extend `UIColor` to conform to `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral` protocol

Tags: swift

I want extend `UIColor` to conform to `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral`. But I see this conformance requires required initializer which cannot be declared in an extension.

Is my intention somehow wrong in terms of thinking in the language or is it language limitation at the moment?

Comment: Seems to be a language limitation, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26498391/swift-implement-literalconvertible-protocol.

Comment: Ah... Generally I like Swift but sometimes it drives me really mad... Currently we are not even able to subclass `UIColor` because it has required initializer in its extension but declarations from extension cannot be overridden. Ironically the class is `open`...